# search facebook application info using api key

Tags: facebook

is there anyway to search for applicaiton info like "connect url","callback url"... etc.. using api key?

Answer (score 1):

No, the admin section of the api doesn't touch any of these.  You need to set these urls using the developer app.

Comment: dont get it, do u mean i need to write an app ot check for other's developer app info?